# Jenkins multiple masters

Tags: jenkins, scalability, load-balancing, high-availability

We are planning to implement a little Jenkins server farm which will continuously build our binaries as code is getting checked in.

- Plan to have around 500-600 odd VMs in this farm

A few questions that arise then are:

1) Should we go with 1 master - multiple slave configuration OR should we have a multiple master-multiple slave configuration? The second seems the obvious choice, however, reading around I found out that resource utilization is much better with the first option.

2) Is there a Jenkins plugin which can facilitate multiple masters - basically so that if a job comes in it is load balanced across the masters which then delegate it to any available slave.

3) Can Jenkins scale upto 500-600 slaves with 1 master alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your proposed configuration it might be worth going with the commercial product from CloudBees http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins/enterprise. They will give you support and also have  load balanced and high availability plugins which the open source version lacks

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of Buildbot.

I found this question by looking at current state of the Art for Jenkins multi-master.

Buildbot since 0.9.3 has multimaster support and can easily support 500-600 slaves (we call them workers)
http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/concepts.html#multimaster

Buildbot is fully open-source, and has a community of freelancers who can help if you need paid support.

Comment: Does Buildbot support Groovy or any other equivalent language? -i.e. Not just shell scripts. I mean, you can imagine migrating an entire cluster will require lots of work. I can't even begin to imagine the amount of work it would take to refactor all our Jenkins pipelines and shared libraries to do them in... whatever Buildbot supports. But if it only supports shell, then no way.

Comment: @Mig82 it is written in Python so you can write other parts you need in python as well.